# Como adicionar "buttons" a Tabbedpanel

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou envolvido num projecto pessoal em que pretendo elaborar uma calculadora com alguns itens que estão inseridos em "arrays". Optei por numa classe chamada "calc.cs" constuir um metodo com um código idêntico a este

```
  public void AddDrinkstoTabbedpanel()
        {

              List<string> drinks = new List<string>();//New list empty
              food foo = new food();//Call food to get drinks
              string [] product = foo.name;//string product [] = food.name (drinks)
              foreach (string value in product)//(string value in product)//for any "value" in product 
              {
                  drinks.Add(value);//Add these value to list

                  Button bt = new Button();//new button(s)
                  bt.Text = value.ToString();//Add text to button 
              }

        }
```

Tentei obter os "items" que estão guardados em "arrays" inserindo:  `Messagebox.Show(value);` e de facto obtenho todos os items que pretendo.

No entanto a solução não me cria para cada item o respectivo botão, porquê?

Onde falhei, o que está mal?

Comment: Esta não é uma questão de C#. Para que plataforma estás a desenvolver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para adicionar um botão a algum componente, você pode usar o método [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

No caso, para adicioná-lo a uma TabPage de uma TabControl, você poderia passar a primeira como parâmetro de seu método:

```
public void AddDrinkstoTabbedpanel(TabPage tp)
        {
            List<string> drinks = new List<string>();
            food foo = new food();
            string[] product = foo.name;
            foreach (string value in product)
            {
                drinks.Add(value);

                Button bt = new Button();
                bt.Text = value.ToString();
                tp.Controls.Add(bt); //Adiciona o botão a TabPage
            }
        }
```